# discord.io to send Image via Discord Bot - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.io

I already create token, and permission and authorize the correct server

[image]

## Code

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
    token: auth.token,
    autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

       args = args.splice(1);
       switch(cmd) {
          // !ping
            case 'ping':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'Pong'
            });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..


    }
    }
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);

        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'img':
            bot.sendMessage("img", {
                file: "https://i.imgur.com/hIK7JKq.jpg" // Or replace with FileOptions object
            });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
        }
    }
});

// I've tried with this Perm Int : 522304
```

Restarted my server

[image]

I tested it

[image]

I don't see any image sent.

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: Was `bot.on('message'` triggered?

Comment: yes it triggered.

Comment: I tried  `!ping`, I got `"pong"`

Comment: Why do you have two "message" listeners exactly? It doesn't make much sense to me, and one of them might not be triggering.

Comment: I had 2 listen because there were some issue when I added another case where the second case kept triggering.

Comment: @MadWard :  Right now, when I tested it with `!img` I don't see any image in the message box.

Comment: @kyo: Several problems in your code. You're not specifying any channel ID to send to in your "img" case. There is no such thing as `sendMessage` to send attachments. The official discord.io method for it is called `uploadFile` and is described in their [docs](https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/Methods/Channels.html).

Comment: @MadWard I used this npm package.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the tag to [tag:discord.io] so that it won't appear in the discord.js section (that is another library!)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Discord.io docs, wouldn't it be `uploadFile`? I could be wrong since I haven't used Discord.io, rather I use Discord.js, so I apologize ahead of time. Something like this:

```js
bot.uploadFile({
    to: id,
    file: FileBuffer
}).catch(console.error);
```

You also shouldn't need two message listeners. You can have everything in a single message event.

```js
bot.on('message', (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) => {
  if (user.bot) return; // prevents bots interacting with one another or itself.
  if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);

    switch (cmd) {
      case 'ping':
      bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Pong'
      }).catch(console.error);
      break;
      case 'img':
      bot.uploadFile({
        to: channelID,
        file: FileBuffer
      }).catch(console.error);
    };
  };
});
```

Extra note: putting `.catch()` on the end of the sending functions will catch Promise errors.

Comment: Where do we specify the path of the file ?

Comment: in the `bot.uplaodFile()` function, with the `file` option. Should be able to send an image with a direct link or `/path/to/img.png/` but doing the later might require to pass `fileName` as well. That or Discord will name it "unknown", which shouldn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example -- https://github.com/izy521/discord.io/blob/master/example.js
You need to get the helper function

```
function sendFiles(channelID, fileArr, interval) {
    var resArr = [], len = fileArr.length;
    var callback = typeof(arguments[2]) === 'function' ? arguments[2] : arguments[3];
    if (typeof(interval) !== 'number') interval = 1000;

    function _sendFiles() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (fileArr[0]) {
                bot.uploadFile({
                    to: channelID,
                    file: fileArr.shift()
                }, function(err, res) {
                    resArr.push(err || res);
                    if (resArr.length === len) if (typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(resArr);
                });
                _sendFiles();
            }
        }, interval);
    }
    _sendFiles();
}
```

Then just

```
sendFiles(channelID, ["ep.gif"]);
```

Comment: I had to have the gif locally. Doesn't work with url.